# How to use getStaticPaths on dynamic nested routes in Next JS?

Tags: next.js

This is my route folder structure:

[image]

I want to achieve a URL structure like this: `http://localhost:3000/brands/toyota/toyota-innova`

On `[brandSlug]/index.js`, I used `getStaticPaths` to define paths and it seems working. When I enter params other than `toyota` and `mitsubishi`, it shows the 404 page which is the desired behavior.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [{ params: { brandSlug: 'toyota' } }, { params: { brandSlug: 'mitsubishi' } }],
        fallback: false,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps() {

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/brands');
    const brands = await response.json();

    return {
        props: {
            brands: brands,
        }
    };
}

const Brand = ({ brands }) => {

    const router = useRouter()
    console.log(brands)

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Showing all vehicles of {router.query.brandSlug}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Brand
```

However, on `[brandSlug]/[vehicleSlug].js`, using the code below, returns an error when I input:

`http://localhost:3000/brands/toyota/toyota-innova`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [{ params: { vehicleSlug: 'toyota-innova' } }, { params: { vehicleSlug: 'toyota-corolla' } }],
        fallback: false,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps() {

    // const response = await fetch('api here');
    // const vehicle = await response.json();

    // gonna fetch vehicle details here, made empty for now

    return {
        props: {
            vehicle: [],
        }
    };
}

const VehicleDetails = () => {

    const router = useRouter()

    return (
        <p>Showing Vehicle details of {`${router.query.vehicleSlug}`}</p>
    )
}

export default VehicleDetails
```

This is the error:

[image]

`Error: A required parameter (brandSlug) was not provided as a string received undefined in getStaticPaths for /brands/[brandSlug]/[vehicleSlug]`

It says missing `brandSlug` but I have already provided it

Is my `nested dynamic route` structure okay with getStaticPaths?

What I was expecting is to be able to enter url `http://localhost:3000/brands/toyota/toyota-innova` and throw 404 page if for example `mitsubishi/toyota-innova` or `toyota/random-parameter123` is used.

How do I properly do that using getStaticPaths and nested dynamic routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided brandSlug in your vehicleSlug getStaticProps.

It should be:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [{ 
            params: { 
               brandSlug: 'toyota',
               vehicleSlug: 'toyota-innova',
            }
        }],
        fallback: false,
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have just figured it out too! It's working now 